# Reload javascript file after oninput event is triggered

Tags: javascript, gradient

I am making an interactive piechart with css conic gradients using Lea Verou's [polyfill](https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/)  It displays the pie chart on the initial page load, but when you change any values in the input the pie becomes blank and only displays a blank circle. I am guessing the polyfill javascript file isn't being retriggered when the oninput event fires.

```js
calcz.oninput = function() { 
var colors = ['red','orange','yellow','lime','aqua', 'violet'];
var gradient = []; var values = []; 
var percents = [0]; var n = 0; var o = 0;
var lengthz = document.forms.calcz.length;
var totalz = 0;
for(var z = 0; z < lengthz-1; z++)
{
totalz += parseFloat(document.forms.calcz[z].value); 
values.push(document.forms.calcz[z].value);
}    

for (var zz = 0; zz < lengthz-1; zz++)
{
percents.push(document.forms.calcz[zz].value/totalz*100);
n += percents[zz]; 
o += percents[zz+1];
gradient.push(colors[zz] + ' ' + n.toFixed(2)+'% ' + o.toFixed(2)+'% ');
}

result.value = totalz;
var h = document.getElementById("piechart");
h.setAttribute('style', 'background:conic-gradient('+gradient+')');
};
calcz.oninput();
```

```css
input[type=number] { width:80px; } 
output {font-weight:bold;} 
#piechart { float:left; width:200px; height:200px; border-radius:50% 50%; border:1px solid black; background-repeat: no-repeat; margin-top:15px; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Interactive Pie Chart</title>
  
</head>
<body>
<form id="calcz">
<div style="float:left; width:50%">
1. <input type="number" value="6000"><br>
2. <input type="number" value="240"><br>
3. <input type="number" value="1440"><br>
4. <input type="number" value="240"><br>
5. <input type="number" value="600"><br> 
6. <input type="number" value="1200"></div>

<div id="piechart"></div> 
<output id="result"></output></form>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/conic-gradient.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm first making sure I can get that conic-gradient working:

```css
#thing {
  background: conic-gradient(#f06, gold);
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="conic-gradient.js"></script>


<div id="thing">
thing here...
</div>
```

With your code, I'm not seeing the gradient at all on first load, but I can when I change this line:

h.setAttribute('style', 'background: conic-gradient(#f06, gold);')

Ex:

```js
calcz.oninput = function() {
console.log('calling function.....')
var colors = ['red','orange','yellow','lime','aqua', 'violet'];
var gradient = []; var values = []; 
var percents = [0]; var n = 0; var o = 0;
var lengthz = document.forms.calcz.length;
var totalz = 0;
for(var z = 0; z < lengthz-1; z++)
{
totalz += parseFloat(document.forms.calcz[z].value); 
values.push(document.forms.calcz[z].value);
}    

for (var zz = 0; zz < lengthz-1; zz++)
{
percents.push(document.forms.calcz[zz].value/totalz*100);
n += percents[zz]; 
o += percents[zz+1];
gradient.push(colors[zz] + ' ' + n.toFixed(2)+'% ' + o.toFixed(2)+'% ');
}
console.warn('gradient here is: ', gradient)

result.value = totalz;
var h = document.getElementById("piechart");
/* h.setAttribute('style', 'background:conic-gradient('+gradient+')') */;
h.setAttribute('style', 'background: conic-gradient(#f06, gold);')
};
calcz.oninput();
```

```css
    input[type=number] { width:80px; } 
    output {font-weight:bold;} 
    #piechart { 
    float:left; 
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    border-radius:50% 50%; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    background-repeat: 
    no-repeat; margin-top:15px; 
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive Pie Chart</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="conic-gradient.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="calcz">
    <div style="float:left; width:50%">
    1. <input type="number" value="6000"><br>
    2. <input type="number" value="240"><br>
    3. <input type="number" value="1440"><br>
    4. <input type="number" value="240"><br>
    5. <input type="number" value="600"><br> 
    6. <input type="number" value="1200"></div>

    <div id="piechart"></div> 
    <output id="result"></output></form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Note that when first running your script, your `gradient` variable is an array that looks like this: `["red 0.00% 61.73% ", "orange 61.73% 64.20% ", "yellow 64.20% 79.01% ", "lime 79.01% 81.48% ", "aqua 81.48% 87.65% ", "violet 87.65% 100.00% "]`

Comment: https://codepen.io/captlid/pen/XPpNmZ It displays fine inside the codepen view in firefox

Comment: hmm, i'm on Chrome, perhaps that's an issue

Comment: Yes as far as I tested that's the CSS its supposed to generate and then the polyfill seems to generate a SVG file based on that data. Yay browsers that don't support conic-gradient tags.

Comment: The codepen displays on chrome version 68 in windows.

Comment: Hmm well is the array the issue? Perhaps the gradient variable should be made into a string? For example: `var gradientString = gradient.join(", ")`

Comment: you're right, just tried it in Firefox and it indeed shows color

Comment: ok well now that i'm seeing the problem when looking at the codepen in Firefox, i'm not sure what the solution is. i added `console.log('gradient is: ', gradient)` above the line `result.value = totalz;` and i'm watching the array change with each click of the inputs. So the function appears to be working correctly, it's just not displaying the colors for some reason.

Comment: Does polyfill code reload on events? This is my first time using one ever.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to reload the the polyfill script, but I did get a working interactive pie chart that reacts on the oninput event working by generating slices with SVG.

https://codepen.io/captlid/pen/wROWKj

The circle has to be 16 radius. The math works out that stroke-dasharray can be say "20 100"  which is 20% and then for the dashoffset you add percent+previouspercent. Stroke width and svg viewbox should be 32.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 32 32">

<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="16" stroke="pink" stroke-dasharray="10 100" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="16" stroke="aqua" stroke-dasharray="55 100" stroke-dashoffset="-10"></circle>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="16" stroke="lime" stroke-dasharray="20 100" stroke-dashoffset="-65"></circle>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="16" stroke="orange" stroke-dasharray="20 100" stroke-dashoffset="-85"></circle>

</svg>
svg { width:200px; height:200px; border-radius:50%; }
circle {fill:transparent; stroke-width:32;}
```